# Put a hyperlink over an input file

Tags: css

How can I put a hyperlink over a textbox using CSS?

```
<a href="#" id="up">click</a>
<input type="file"></input>
```

I want to hide the file input and make the hyperlink visible over the file input so it shows for the user that he's clicking the hyperlink to browse his files and not the file input.

Answer (score 1):

You can just set the input's opacity to 0, so it's invisible, then just position a `<p>` tag on top (or `<a>` if you prefer.

```
<div id="container">
<p>Browse</p>
<input type="file"/>
</div>
```

And this CSS

```
#container input {
   opacity: 0;
   height:30px;
   width:100px;
}
#container{
   height:30px;
   width:100px;
    background-color:#ccc;
}
#container p {
   position:absolute;
   text-align:center;
   height:30px;
   width:100px;
}
```

That way you can just style your `<p>` to be some awesome button :)

Answer (score 0):

See this article: www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html

It covers all the different methods, however you're going to have to use an image, not a link.